# How to use Wamp Server database url in Android

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to save the username and password in a database, but the app is unfortunately closed. I can't understand what url is used in the java file and how make the url of the Wamp server database.

Please explain this and solve.
Thanks For your Suggestion in advance.

```
  09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370): android.view.WindowLeaked:             
  Activity com.example.mysqltest.Register has leaked window            
  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2d949b8 V.E..... 
   R.....ID 0,0-304,96} that was originally added here
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at   
   android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)

   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at  
  android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
    09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at 
    android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
  09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
  android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
    09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at  
   com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:86)
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at 
    android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
      09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
    android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at   
   com.example.mysqltest.Register.onClick(Register.java:68)
  09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at 
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
      09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):    at 
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):   at 

  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):     at  
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):     at  
  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i m use this url private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/webservice/login.php";

Comment: Please post relevant part of your code and the log cat too. without that i don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: 09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2d949b8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-304,96} that was originally added here
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)

Comment: 09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at com.example.mysqltest.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:86)
09-15 07:51:34.866: E/WindowManager(3370):  at

Comment: Please edit your question and post the logcat there. its hard to read it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to access mysql database directly from android app. You can create a simple web service with php and then call to that service 
with a HTTP Client.

Comment: i know but what url use

Comment: You can send a POST request to a url something like http://hostname/api/v1/user with a json object {"username": "youname", "password": "yourpassword"} . Which url you should use is up to you when you design the web service in php